# Inner selection in LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <name>Super 1</name>
        <types>
            <type>Art</type>
            <type>Retro</type>
        </types>
    </project>
    <project>
        <name>Super 2</name>
        <types>
            <type>Retro</type>
        </types>
    </project>
</projects>
```

I need to implement `SelectProjectsOfType(string type)` method. It should return all the `<project>`'s `XElement`s with a given type listed as one of their inner `<type>` in `<types>` collection. So I need to first analyse the types in each element, and then select an entire project node if the type in search is present. How can this be elegantly done in using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XElement projects = ...;
string searchTerm = "some-type-of-project";

var result = projects.Descendents("project").Where(
  p => p.Descendents("type").Any(t => t.Value == searchTerm)
);
```